# H2 data base remote connection with mixed mode (Auto_server= true)

Tags: h2

I need to install same application on two computers. I want to use h2 database in mixed mode i.e AUTO_SERVER= TRUE. But my problem is that how to connect to this database from computer 2 while database files are stored in Computer 1.
as per docs, url ="jdbc:h2:/dbfile;AUTO_SERVER= TRUE"
I am not able to get the DBPATH working for both the computers.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Server mode](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server).

Basically what you are trying to do is network communication. There should be an address, so you need to make Computer1 with static IP (local).

In my understand The meaning of mixed mode is you can access same db with two or more Apps not different computers.